# How to create falling snow in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

I have this code:

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    pX = randomGenerator.nextInt(CAMERA_WIDTH);
    Sprite snow = new Sprite (pX, 1, 30, 30, mTextureSnowRegion);
    scene.getLastChild().attachChild(snow);
    return scene;
}
```

I am trying to make a snowfall. I was trying to use a MoveModifier, but nothing is work.
Please help.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-30days-apps/source/browse/trunk/08day/src/com/bakhtiyor/android/snowfall/SnowFall.java?spec=svn27&r=27
This link may helpful to you

Comment: You should accept one of the answers talking about particle systems, because that is probably the best way to create snow in AndEngine.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a particle system in AndEngine: http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/ParticleSystemSimpleExample.java

Answer (score 1):

```
public Scene onLoadScene() {
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
pX = randomGenerator.nextInt(CAMERA_WIDTH);
Sprite snow = new Sprite (pX, 1, 30, 30, mTextureSnowRegion);
scene.getLastChild().attachChild(snow);
return scene;
```

This looks good. You just need to add MoveYModifer instead of MoveModifier.

And also you should use an GenericPool in AndEngine, because it uses alot of memory to keep creating new Sprite instances and attaching it. Also dont forget to detach it when the sprite is gone off screen.

Check out this

Answer (score 1):

Using this particle code in my game to create snow. My game uses a 800x480 camera.

```
    final RectangleParticleEmitter particleEmitter = new RectangleParticleEmitter(184.0f,44.0f,340,60);
    final ParticleSystem particleSystem = new ParticleSystem(particleEmitter, 100, 200, 360, this.mParticleTextureRegion);


    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ColorInitializer(1, 1, 1));
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new AlphaInitializer(0));
    particleSystem.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE);
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityInitializer(-200, 200, -200, 200));
    particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new RotationInitializer(0.0f, 360.0f));

    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ScaleModifier(1.0f, 1.2f, 0, 5));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1, 0.98f, 1, 0.96f, 1, 0.82f, 0, 3));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ColorModifier(1, 1, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1, 4, 6));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new org.anddev.andengine.entity.particle.modifier.AlphaModifier(0, 1, 0, 1));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new org.anddev.andengine.entity.particle.modifier.AlphaModifier(1, 0, 5, 6));
    particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new ExpireModifier(3, 6));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using similar particle system settins as @UncleIstvan.

```
final BatchedPseudoSpriteParticleSystem particleSystem = new BatchedPseudoSpriteParticleSystem(
    new RectangleParticleEmitter(CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, CAMERA_HEIGHT, CAMERA_WIDTH, 1),
    2, 5, 100, mSnowParticleRegion, 
    this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()
  );
particleSystem.setBlendFunction(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE);
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new VelocityParticleInitializer<Entity>(-3, 3, -20, -40));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new AccelerationParticleInitializer<Entity>(-3, 3, -3, -5));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new RotationParticleInitializer<Entity>(0.0f, 360.0f));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ExpireParticleInitializer<Entity>(10f));
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new ScaleParticleInitializer<Entity>(0.2f, 0.5f));


particleSystem.addParticleModifier(new AlphaParticleModifier<Entity>(6f, 10f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

scene.attachChild(particleSystem);
```

But I added an entity modifier to each particle:

```
particleSystem.addParticleInitializer(new RegisterXSwingEntityModifierInitializer<Entity>(10f, 0f, (float) Math.PI * 8, 3f, 25f, true));
```

It needs a custom particle initializer. In the initializer I register a new modifier to each particle:

```
@Override
public void onInitializeParticle(Particle<T> pParticle) {
        pParticle.getEntity().registerEntityModifier(
                new PositionXSwingModifier(mDuration, 
                        mFromValue, mToValue, 
                        mFromMagnitude, mToMagnitude));

}
```

And the last part is the modifier that uses growing sine wave to create the swinging motion (some parts ommited):

```
public class PositionXSwingModifier extends SingleValueSpanEntityModifier {

  public PositionXSwingModifier(float pDuration, float pFromValue, float pToValue,
        float pFromMagnitude, float pToMagnitude) {
    // fromValue is usually 0
    // toValue means how many times will the sine wave oscillate
    // every 2pi is full sin wave
    super(pDuration, pFromValue, pToValue);
    mFromMagnitude = pFromMagnitude;
    mToMagnitude = pToMagnitude;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSetValue(IEntity pItem, float pPercentageDone, float pValue) {
    // current magnitude based on percentage
    float currentMagnitude = mFromMagnitude + (mToMagnitude - mFromMagnitude) * pPercentageDone;
    // current sine wave value
    float currentSinValue = (float) Math.sin(pValue);
    // change the x position of the flake
    pItem.setX(mInitialX + currentMagnitude * currentSinValue);
  }

}
```

It's based partly on my question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56475/how-to-simulate-feather-fall-in-box2d

And you can get the full code and the APK to try it out [here](http://android.kul.is/2013/09/tutorial-how-to-create-falling-snow-in.html).